# Solution for problem related to uniformly distributed points in a Circle.

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, circles, uniform-distribution

Given the rough representation of my scenario below. I am confused about how to proceed with my analysis. I will explain it as follows

Red-point (RP) (Fixed position) is the user which experience interference from the Green point (GP) (Uniformly distributed anywhere in the circle). (Note the GP can be ANYWHERE withing the circle with radius $r_x$, while RP is fixed to the distance $r_c$)

The distance between Red-point and Green point $r$ such that $r \sim U(0,r_c + r_x)$. Since the GP is the Interfering Source. I consider it as the interfering transmitter with Channel distribution $h \sim \exp(1)$
[image]

For the sake of brevity, I can't explain the whole process, but the Eq. for interference comes up to be:

$$\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \mathbb{E}[\exp(-shr^{-\alpha})]$$
where $s$ is the constant, $\mathcal{L}(s)$ denotes the Laplace Transform, $h\sim\exp(1)$, $r\sim U(0,r_c+r_x)$, $\alpha$ is a constant. $I$ is the interference that I am trying to calculate.

**Now I proceed as follows (I need both suggestions if I am doing right + how to proceed further).**

$$\mathbb{E}[I] =\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \mathbb{E}_r[\mathbb{E}_h[\exp(-shr^{-\alpha})]]$$

since $\mathcal{L}_x(s)$ for $x \sim \exp(1) = \frac{1}{1+s}$, so

$$\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \mathbb{E}_r\Big[\frac{1}{1+sr^{-\alpha}}\Big]$$

I know that for $x \sim U(a,b)$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{a+b}{2}$, but I don't know how to implement it here. Is the following answer correct:

$$\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \frac{1}{1+s(2/(r_c+r_x))^{-\alpha}} $$
$$\mathcal{L}_I(s) = \frac{1}{1+s((r_c+r_x)/)^{\alpha}} $$
$$\mathbb{E}[I] = \frac{1}{1+(\frac{r_c+r_x}{2}s^{1/\alpha})^{\alpha}} $$

Comment: May be final $E[I]$ is wrong, but I am still working on it using Law of the unconscious statistician

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your description: if the green point is always *on* the outer circle, the red point is *fixed on* the inner circle and the two circles are also fixed, how can the distance between the two points be uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,r_c+r_x)$? i.e. how can the two points come any closer than $r_x-r_c$? Also you haven't defined the quantity $I$ anywhere in your question.

Comment: The green point can be anywhere on the circle, ANYWHERE. While the Red point is fixed. It is just a rough pictorial representation. $I$ is the interference. These edits have been made in the question now

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that $\mathcal{L}_I$ is the Laplace transform of $I$ and the relation between $I$ and $h$, $r$ given by the first expression. Am I understanding this right? So to calculate $E(I)$ all you need to do is differentiate $\mathcal{L}_I$.

Comment: Are $r$ and $h$ independent?

Comment: Yes they are independent. and $\mathcal{L}$ is from my solution, here just consider it as a symbol.

Comment: Since you did not define $I$ explicitly, if we want to calculate $E(I)$ (that is the goal, right?), there needs to be some relation between $I$  and $h,r$ (the known quantities). What is that relation?

Comment: $I$ is the interference, and yes to find $E[I]$ is the ultimate goal is broken down to $E_r[E_h[\frac{1}{1 + shr^{-alpha}}]]$. So you should not thing about $I$. It is here just for the sake of completion of equation